# Adapt font height to get same size of another text

Tags: fontsize, adjustwidth, variable

I have the following command:

```
\newcommand\adaptwidth{2}{\1

\2}
```

When I use it like this `\adaptwidth{foo}{bar}`, I get the following rendering:

[image: Frist line smaller than second one]

Then, I want to adjust the width of *bar* by varying the font height and get something like:
[image: Two lines with the same width]

So, how can I get the width of the first argument and then divide it by the width of the second to get the correct font height of *bar*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possibility, making the 2nd argument conform to the width of the 1st argument, shown for cases where the 1st argument is naturally shorter than the 2nd, as well as vice-versa.

The vertical presentation shows that they are, in fact, matched in width.  I comment out several other styles of presentation.

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{scalerel,graphicx}
\newcommand\matchfirstwidth[2]{\leavevmode%
  \setbox8=\hbox{\strut#1}\dp8=0pt%
  \setbox4=\hbox{\rotatebox[origin=lb]{90}{\copy8}}%
  \setbox8=\hbox{\strut#2}\dp8=0pt%
  \setbox2=\hbox{\rotatebox[origin=lb]{90}{\copy8}}%
  \setbox6=\hbox{\rotatebox[origin=rb]{-90}{\scalerel*{\copy2}{\copy4}}}%
  \setbox8=\hbox{\rotatebox[origin=rb]{-90}{\scalerel{\copy2\,}{\copy4}}}%
%{\fboxsep=0pt\fbox{\copy8}}%
% or
\copy8%
% or
%{\fboxsep=0pt\fbox{\scaleto{\copy8}{2\baselineskip}}}
}
\begin{document}
\matchfirstwidth{foo}{bar}\quad
\matchfirstwidth{bar}{foo}\quad
\matchfirstwidth{foogoo}{bar}\quad
\matchfirstwidth{bar}{foogoo}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And, as followed up by the OP, to reverse the vertical sense of the two items,

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{scalerel,graphicx}
\newcommand\matchfirstwidth[2]{\leavevmode%
  \setbox8=\hbox{\strut#1}\dp8=0pt%
  \setbox4=\hbox{\rotatebox[origin=lb]{90}{\copy8}}%
  \setbox8=\hbox{\strut#2}\dp8=0pt%
  \setbox2=\hbox{\rotatebox[origin=lb]{90}{\copy8}}%
  \setbox8=\hbox{\rotatebox[origin=rb]{-90}{\copy4\,\scalerel*{\copy2}{\copy4}}}%
%{\fboxsep=0pt\fbox{\copy8}}%
% or
\copy8%
% or
%{\fboxsep=0pt\fbox{\scaleto{\copy8}{2\baselineskip}}}
}
\begin{document}
\matchfirstwidth{foo}{bar}\quad
\matchfirstwidth{bar}{foo}\quad
\matchfirstwidth{foogoo}{bar}\quad
\matchfirstwidth{bar}{foogoo}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! But is it possible to make it also work when the first argument is smaller than the second?

Comment: I have another question: Why do you permute the first and second argument? In my own code I reverse it. But I think you should have a god reason.

Comment: @fauve You had said in the original question, "Then, I want to adjust the width of bar by varying the font height" where "bar" was the 2nd argument.  Since the 1st argument went unchanged, I thought it made sense to leave that on the baseline.  However, if you want it switched, I have provided additional code.

Comment: @fauve as to your question, "is it possible to make it also work when the first argument is smaller than the second," it already does.  In the 4th case of both examples, the natural width of `bar` is smaller than `foogoo`.